# Can not retrieve thumbnailLink from google drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, thumbnails

I am trying to get the thumbnailLink from files from a shared drive using python and the google Drive API, however, the file information does not include the thumbnailLink (although for most files the hasThumbnail field, which i do get as a field for the file, has a value of true)

I have looked around a lot and none of the solutions i have found seem to work (although this is my first python project as well as my first google drive api project, so i might just be ignorant of what i am doing)

What i have tried:
- setting the scope to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' (was ..drive.metadata.readonly before)
- using a wildcard as such: `results = drive.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="*",blablabla...)`. If i for instance try fields="thumbnailLink" it doesn't find any files.
- after getting the list, i tried using the id of each file from that list to do `file = service.files().get(fileId=item_id, supportsAllDrives=True, fields="*").execute()` but the same happens, i have many fields including the hasThumbnail field which is set to true, yet no thumbnail link.
- i tried using the "Try this API" console on the official website, where i did in fact get the thumbnailLink!! (with the same parameters as above). So i do not understand why this is missing when requested from my application.

Edit (code):
i have one method like so

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def getDrive():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=53209)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    return service
```

then i call it from here and also get the files:

```
def getFiles(request):
    drive = getDrive()
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = drive.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="*", driveId="blabla", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, corpora="drive", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])
    getItems = []
    for item in items:
        item_id = item['id']
        getItems.append(drive.files().get(fileId=item_id, supportsAllDrives=True, fields="*").execute())
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        print(getItems)
        for item in items:
            # print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            print(item)

    return render(request, "index.html", {'files': getItems})
```

Also, yes, i do use a service account, i can retrieve all the files i need, just not the thumbnailLink.

I don't think it makes sense to call list() and then also get() but i had read that the problem could be solved through the get() method, which in my case did not work.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the mimeType of the file you want to retrieve the thumbnail link? 2. Can I see your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: Can you provide your full code please? Are you using a service account?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response! i have updated the question above, let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

### The issue is in the structure of the response

If you specify `fields="*"`, the response would be something like

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
  ...
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
    ...
   "hasThumbnail": true,
   "thumbnailLink": "XXX",
   "thumbnailVersion": "XXX"
    ...
  }
  ..
 ]
}
```

So, `thumbnailLink` is nested inside of `files`.

**In order to retrieve it specify:**

`fields='files(id, thumbnailLink)'`

Comment: Thank you, but this does not fix the issue. I have tried your implementation, however i just get the id returned, no thumbnailLink. Beyond that, if i pass the "items" object to the context, instead of the "getItems" one, i already retrieve the "files" part in the line ```items = results.get('files', [])``` 
The model json you put here is pretty much exactly what i get, just that the thumbnailLink field is missing completely (even for those items that have "hasThumbnail:true"

Comment: So when you specify `fields="*"` you obtain `"hasThumbnail": true` but at the same time `thumbNailLink` is empty? And this happens only if you retrieve the files n Python with a Service account, not when you authenticate as you or when you use the `Try this API`?

Comment: that is exactly right. when i specify `fields="*"` i get `"hasThumbnail"=true`, even the thumbnail version, yet no `thumbnailLink`. `Try this API` with the exact same, copy-pasted parameters does indeed return the link, while when my application receives the data, there is no link.

Comment: Sounds like a permisison issue for the service account. Did you try programmatically without service account or with impesonation?

Comment: What i did was use an existing user account that had access to the files and created the API key and everything for that account. Does that make sense? (not quite sure if i understand the question, i think im just to new to this)

Comment: If you can see the thumbnail with the Try this API - I assume you authenticate as yourself? Why don't you do the same when doing it programmatically? (With the token creation rather than API keys). Please delete your `token.pickle` file and try again (it needs to be deleted if you ever changed scopes). Make sure you try it for the same file as you did with `Try this API`.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for not replying in such a long time, weird year last year. I did use the same account for both. I was enthusiastic to delete the `token.pickle` file, thought we finally found it, but sadly... to no avail..